# Which Isolation level would better to avoid exclusive lock in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

In my c# application everywhere isolation level set to **read committed** for transaction. I know that is to prevent dirty read from database.

But in some point of time it takes exclusive locks as well where if long running query executing in database which takes time to complete.

e.g. Let suppose I have written a query which takes time to execute in sql database. On the other hand somebody performs some action from GUI that goes through transaction (read committed) in the application. So, at this point it takes exclusive lock I guess and wait to complete sql query execution which still running. Then it gives timeout error.

Could someone please tell which Isolation level I should use for transaction in my application just to avoid lock? and could perform or run insert,update and delete in transaction regardless long running query executing in sql server instance.

Any suggestion most appreciated. Thanks!

BR

Comment: "Read uncommitted" wont take any read locks but will allow dirty reads.

Comment: [Snapshot isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/tcbchxcb) is your friend. Do not apply it blindly, because it trades locking for update conflicts, which need to be handled explicitly. But for applications where the updates are not expected to conflict and readers should not be blocked it's close to ideal. It's certainly better than `READ UNCOMMITTED` in many cases, as it preserves data consistency (the data you read may be *old*, but it won't be inconsistent or incomplete, as may very well happen under `UNCOMMITTED`).

Comment: If I use Snapshot isolation then how I will handle update conflicts explicitly?

Comment: If all you care is readers not blocking writers, don't use snapshot isolation in modification statements (just leave this to locking) and use snapshot isolation only for `SELECT` statements (those cannot generate conflicts). If you apply snapshot isolation throughout, you need to be prepared to handle `SqlExceptions` that indicate an update conflict and implement a retry policy.

Comment: In my application there is no possibility that two users are updating same set of records at same time because once user take lock from application it won't possible to work for others on same sets.Question, would it also conflicts if multiple users are updating same table but not same records from other transactions?

Comment: In general, no. Locks are as granular as possible, which usually means row locks taken for as short a time as possible. For snapshot isolation, definitely no, since conflict detection is done based on row versions (actual modifications).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143302/discussion-between-yogesh-and-jeroen-mostert).